# how to connect scylladb from rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to connect to scyllaDB from Rust code which is giving error as

> thread 'main' panicked at 'General("timed out waiting for connection")'

Code is

```
pub fn create_db_session() -> CDRSResult<CurrentSession> {
    println!("connecting to db");
    let auth = NoneAuthenticator;
    let node = NodeTcpConfigBuilder::new("9.78.45.122:32028", auth).build();
    let cluster_config = ClusterTcpConfig(vec![node]);
    new_session(&cluster_config, SingleNode::new())
}
```

Dependencies I am using

```
[dependencies]
cdrs = "2"
cdrs_helpers_derive = "0.1.0"
uuid = "0.7"
time = "0.1"
```

From Python, I am able to connect to the same IP/PORT, but not with Rust.

Working Python Code

```
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='None')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url=scylla_host,
                          region_name='None', aws_access_key_id='None', aws_secret_access_key='None')
```

What is the issue with Rust code?

Comment: From the python code it looks like you're trying to connect to the DynamoDB API (a.k.a. alternator), while cdrs is a driver for CQL query language - which is the API of Cassandra. Scylla supports both APIs, but each one requires an appropriate driver. Perhaps you meant to use a DynamoDB Rust driver to connect to the alternator interface? E.g. https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_dynamodb/index.html ?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this blog post that explains how to use CDRS Rust driver to connect to Scylla https://www.scylladb.com/2020/04/21/using-the-cdrs-rust-driver-with-scylla/.

Recently, we also have developed a very experimental version of a fully async driver during our Hackathon that you can find here https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-rust-driver.

Answer (score 0):

Also, an update to this: we have a new shard-aware Rust driver that surpasses CDRS in terms of speed and functionality:

https://www.scylladb.com/2021/07/13/scylla-rust-driver-update-and-benchmarks/